# Как реализовать поворот двумерного вектора на 45 градусов?

Tags: c++, vector

Как реализовать поворот двумерного вектора на 45 градусов, нашел решения для 90, 180, 270. Такой повопрот можно реализовать только через матрицу поворота?

Еще вопрос, касательно дальнейшего использования элементов вектора

```
int E;
cout << " Input E ";
cin >> E;
for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y)
{
    if ((array[y][y] == (min - E)) || (array[y][y] == (min + E)))
    {
        cout << "Element #" << y+1 << ":match  ";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Element #" << y + 1 << ":not match  ";
    }
}
```

В данном случае, значения просто проверяются на совпадения с условием(что и логично), но как реализовать, что значения, которые подходят использовались для дальнейших расчетов?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы повернуть двумерный вектор `(x, y)` на угол `a`, надо проделать следующие вычисления (обратите внимание, что `a` здесь измеряется в радианах, а не в градусах):

```
cs = cos(a);
sn = sin(a);    
rx = x * cs - y * sn;
ry = x * sn + y * cs;
```

Соответственно, в случае поворота на 45 градусов синус и косинус равны `sqrt(2)/2`, поэтому результирующий вектор `(rx, ry)` можно найти так:

```
cs = sn = sqrt(2)/2;
rx = x * cs - y * sn;
ry = x * sn + y * cs;
```

На второй Ваш вопрос про использование в дальнейших вычислениях ответить крайне сложно, потому что нет ясности, в чём он состоит. Возможно, Вы хотите значения, подходящие под условия, добавлять в какой-то список, чтобы потом их обработать. Поясните, что именно тут надо.

Comment: За первый ответ спасибо) Очень выручили. Касательного второго, в дальнейшем, я хочу использовать значения для расчет евклидова расстояния. Я нашел значения, но как их использовать сразу в уравнение не понимаю

Comment: Понятнее-то не стало. Продолжаю подозревать, что Вам надо добавлять подходящие значения в отдельный список, а потом провести над ними нужные вычисления.

Comment: Эх, как бы поточнее сформулировать вопрос. Я отсеял значения в моем двумерном векторе на соотвествие условию. Теперь я хочу, чтобы значения, что подошли, я мог использовать в решение уравнения. Например - если в моей матрице есть числа подходящие под условия(к примеру E1=max+x и E2=min+х) то я мог бы их использовать отдельно от матрицы и уравнение. Надеюсь стало понятнее. Кстати, а как их добавить в отдельный список?

Comment: Чтобы добавить элемент `y+1` в список `lst`, выполните `lst.append(y+1)`.

Comment: Замечу, что тут развёрнуто умножение на матрицу поворота. Это самый простой способ :)

Answer (score 1):

Что бы отсеять лишние элементы есть 2 пути:

1. Фильтрация существующего набора данных. Для этого в стандартной библиотеке есть функция [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)
2. Создание нового набора, на основе данного. Для этого используется [copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: Совсем запутался с реализацией, как создать новый набор? Я же не знаю точных значений, которые нужно добавить в этот набор. Матрица заполняется рандомно. Как в этом случае реализовать создание  наобра так, чтобы туда добавлялись значения, которые будут удовлетворять требованиям?

Comment: @Castly6 Вы же обрабатываете не матрицу, а её диагональ, которую можно представить в линейном виде. Например, скопировав все элементы в `std::vector`.